# Surprising Summation (3): $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2(n-i)+1=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$

Tags: summation

Show that

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2(n-i)+1=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$$

without expanding the summation to its closed-form solution, i.e. $\dfrac 16n(n+1)(2n+1)$ or equivalent.

*Background as requested:*
The summands for both equations are not the same but the results are the same. The challenge here is to transform LHS into RHS without solving the summation. It seems like an interesting challenge. If you like this question, please vote to reopen it!

Comment: In one of your summations, you are summing over $j$ but have no $j$ index term..

Comment: yes, that's correct, but it's perfectly acceptable!

Comment: no, it doesn't...

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. I shouldn't try and do maths when tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i (2(n-i)+1)
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=j}^n (2(n-i)+1)
\qquad \text{(switch order of summation)}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{n-j} (2i+1)
\qquad (i \to n-i)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(n-j+1)^2
\qquad\text{(since }\sum_{j=0}^m (2j+1) = (m+1)^2)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n j^2
\qquad (j \to n-j+1)\\
\end{array}

Comment: That's exactly the way I would have proceeded!!  +1

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Very nice approach (+1). I used the substitution of $(n-i+1)$ but it's similar. The last step requires knowing that the sum of the first  $m$ odd numbers equals $m^2$. Is it possible to modify the answer so that it does not require this prior knowledge? The objective is to find an "empirical" proof using only first principles.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it works its way from LHS to RHS without first knowing what RHS is, and without expanding to the known result of any summation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}(2(n-i)+1)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2n+1)i-3\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$$
$$=(2n+1)\frac n2(n+1)-3\times\frac n6(n+1)(2n+1)=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The question did specify not using expansion though. Would you be able to modify your answer taking this into consideration?

Comment: what do you mean by expansion exactly, and where has this occurred?

Comment: Expansion of the summation meaning using the formulas for $\sum_{i=1}^ni$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$.

Comment: so you want to arrive at the result by manipulation of summation limits only?

Comment: Yes, or other similar methods, as long as no expansion is involved. Or perhaps the term should be closed-form solution.

Comment: not sure what you mean by the last sentence. have you thought of maybe rephrasing your question to make it more specific?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what your interpretation of the question is, in particular the part about not using expansion?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following (discrete version of $\int x^k\,dx = \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$):

> **Lemma**: if $p(x)$ is a polynomial having degree $k$, then:
>   $$ P(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}p(k) $$
>   is a polynomial with degree $k+1$.

That lemma gives that both sides are third degree polynomials in $n$. If you check that both sides agree for $n=1,2,3,4$, it follows that they are the same polynomial, hence your identity holds for every $n$.

**Proof of the lemma:** we may write any polynomial in the binomial base, then the [well-known identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk):
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1} $$
proves the claim.

Comment: The statement "we may write any polynomial in the binomial base" would seem to require a proof, or, at least, a link. Personally, I have never seen the phrase "binomial base" though I understand what it means and can readily supply a proof.

Comment: @martycohen: well, we just need induction. $$x^k-k!\binom{x}{k}$$ is a polynomial having degree strictly less than $k$.

Comment: That is a good way to do it. Maybe, while doing that, you could also throw in a proof that a polynomial takes only integer values at the integers iff it is the sum of integers times those binomials.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I agree that using binomials for summation is a useful technique. However, to show that it is the sum of squares would require expansion of the binomials. The objective was to arrive at the answer using basic reindexing, etc. and without expansion.

Comment: @hypergeometric: wait, I just used the fact that a decomposition exists to prove the claim. $i^2$ is a second-degree polynomial in $i$, hence $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$ is a third-degree polynomial in $n$, without computing anything.

Comment: Yes that's correct - point taken. So in your answer just after the yellow box are you saying that we would just have to check the LHS=RHS in the equation to be proven for $n=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: exactly so.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite an interesting approach! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i2(n-i)+1
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2(n-i+1)-1\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^n\sum_{r=s}^n (2s-1)
&& (\text{putting }s=n-i+1\text{ and } r=n-j+1)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{s=1}^r (2s-1)
&&(1\le s\le r\le n)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{s=1}^r s^2-(s-1)^2\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n r^2\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$